# Почему алиас «cd» работает так странно?

Tags: linux, bash

Хотел сделать алиас `cd`, который будет сразу перечислять директории.

Попробовал все следующие варианты:

```
alias 'cd'='cd $1; l'
alias 'cd'='cd $1; l $1'
alias 'cd'='cd $1 && l'
alias 'cd'='cd $1 && l $1'
```

Где, `l` (строчная «L») — алиас другого приложения (`tree`).

> Всегда перегружал терминал, чтобы наверняка, так как `. ~/.bash_aliases` у меня почему-то не срабатывает.

Все вышеперечисленные алиасы при вводе `cd /` перечисляют список директорий / файлов в точке монтирования `/`, однако смена директории не происходит.

Тогда я попробовал прописать в том же `.bash_aliases` функцию (оба варианта<s>, по очереди</s>):

```
cd() {
    cd $1
    l
}

function cd() {
    cd $1
    l
}
```

В итоге, при выполнении `cd /` команда «виснет» ...

Единственный способ, который я нашёл, это сделать так:

```
cdl() {
    cd $1
    l
}
```

То есть задать другое имя ... Но в тоже время, если вернуться к первому варианту алиаса:

```
alias 'cd'='cd $1; l'
```

Здесь же срабатывает `cd` при вводе `cd /`, так как `l` перечисляет список директорий / файлов по пути `/`, так почему же тогда он возвращает обратно в домашнюю директорию?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. *псевдоним оболочки* (*shell alias*) — это не функция и не программа. у *псевдонима* нет аргументов, его описание всего лишь подставляется в команду вместо его имени. поэтому, если вы определили, например, такой *псевдоним*:

   ```
   $ alias cd='cd $1; ls'
   ```

   то при вводе команды

   ```
   $ cd /tmp
   ```

   она преобразуется в

   ```
   $ cd ; ls /tmp
   ```

   обратите внимание на пустое место после `cd` — туда ничего не будет подставлено (вместо `$1`), т.к. переменная `$1` не содержит никакого значения.

   в результате вашим текущим каталогом станет ваш домашний каталог (так действует внутренняя команда `cd`, если ей не передать никаких параметров), а затем будет выполнена команда `ls /tmp`.
2. когда вы определяете функцию:

   ```
   $ function cd() { cd $1; ls; }
   ```

   команда `cd $1` внутри её тела трактуется как рекурсивное обращение к этой же функции, вот и происходит «зависание». кстати, обратите внимание, что в теле *псевдонима* не происходит такой рекурсии — `cd $1` там трактуется именно как обращение к **внутренней команде оболочки** `cd`.

---

и напоследок, в виде факультативного дополнения к ответу на вопрос «почему», приведу пример того, как сделать, чтобы «работало так, как хочется»:

```
$ function cd() { command cd "$@"; ls; }
```

1. использовать надо именно функцию (кстати, само ключевое слово `function` в данном случае — опционально), чтобы получить и обработать список аргументов.
2. для вызова внутренней команды оболочки надо использовать внутреннюю же команду `command`.
3. правильнее передавать не только первый аргумент, а **все** аргументы (`$@`), а чтобы корректно обрабатывались спец-символы (например, пробелы/кавычки и т.п.) внутри аргументов, список лучше заключить в двойные кавычки (`"$@"`).