# Автопереход в последнюю открытую директорию

Tags: linux, bash

Нужно, чтобы в системе у каждого пользователя сохранялся его каталог, в котором он находился перед выходом из системы. И чтобы при следующем логине, пользователь автоматически попадал в этот каталог.

Comment: в терминале что ли?

Comment: если только в терминале, то можно алиасом перекрыть cd и сохранять постоянно его. А при логине, когда отрабатывает bash_rc (или его аналоги), просто делать переход в данный каталог. Но если человек открыл несколько терминалов, то тут проблема:)

Comment: @KoVadim, помимо внутренней команды оболочки `cd`, есть ещё внутренние команды `pushd` и `popd`.

Comment: да, а можно и в zsh просто печатая имя каталога переходить в него.

Comment: @KoVadim, ну, это уже к делу не относится — в вопросе речь про bash. а то ведь так можно и собственную оболочку написать с блэкджеком и оригинальным способом смены текущего каталога текущего процесса (если ещё не написана).

Comment: @KoVadim, псевдонимом, кстати, [не получится](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/590197/178576).

Comment: да, с алиасами плохо получилось. Но всегда можно пропатчить баш  и сделать как нужно.

Comment: в zsh есть cdr команда из zshcontrib, которая автоматически список поддерживает недавних директорий, используя файлы. Ваш случай (только одна функция) легко руками реализовать (без cdr, pushd): в `~/.zlogout`: `echo $PWD >~/.last-dir` и соответственно в `~/.zlogin`: `cd $(<~/.last-dir)` (не тестировал)

Comment: у меня есть лучше идея. А почему при старте терминала не запускать screen/tmux? тогда и проблема решиться. Даже для изысканных случаев (например, сервер отвалился, так как уборщица решила роутер помыть тряпочкой).

Answer (score 2):

можно воспользоваться поддерживаемой программой *bash* возможностью выполнять произвольную указанную команду в момент времени **перед** выводом строки приглашения.

когда вы используете программу *bash* в качестве интерактивной оболочки, то после выполнения очередной введённой вами команды программа выводит строку приглашения. обычно она выглядит примерно как

```
пользователь@хост текущий_каталог $
```

вот как раз перед выводом этой информации *bash* выполняет команду, указанную в переменной окружения `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

на этом можно «сыграть», реализовав в этой команде сохранение имени текущего каталога (можно получить встроенной команандой `pwd`) в каком-нибудь файле. например, в `~/.lastpwd`.

а при загрузке программы *bash* в интерактивном режиме, т.е., при выполнении пользовательского скрипта `~/.bashrc`, выполнять команду, считывающую содержимое упомянутого файла, и выполняющего команду `cd прочитанное_значение`.

---

оба указанных момента можно реализовать такой парой строк, добавляемой в конец скрипта `~/.bashrc`:

```
cd $(cat ${HOME}/.lastpwd 2>/dev/null)
PROMPT_COMMAND="pwd > ${HOME}/.lastpwd"
```

---

побочные эффекты:

- если запустить ещё один экземпляр программы *bash* в интерактивном режиме (например, запустив ещё один *x-эмулятор терминала*), то в ней текущим каталогом станет тот, который сейчас является текущим у первого экземпляра программы.
- если запущено более одного экзепляра программы *bash* в интерактивном режиме, и у них текущими в данный момент являются разные каталоги, и вы выполняете команды то в одном экземпляре, то в другом (то в третьем и т.д.), то в файл `~/.lastpwd` будет попадать имя то одного, то другого (то третьего и т.д.) каталога. в общем, «кто последним обновил файл, того и тапки».

Comment: предлагаю улучшение - сохранять не в .lastpwd, а в .lastpwd$$ (что бы взять пид консоли). Теперь при запуске мы можем отследить это и поднять несколько консолек с правильными путями.

Comment: @jfs, скопировал не из той строчки. спасибо, исправил.

Comment: @KoVadim, это ж целых строчки три кода надо написать! по-моему, тянет на отдельный ответ. кстати, особо прикольно станет где-нибудь через месяц-год, когда при старте сессии будут загружаться тысячи x-терминалов.

Comment: а вот это лечиться просто. После того, как все терминалы стартанули, нужно поудалять эти файлы. Правда тут нужно не грохнуть новые. Для этго, вначале все эти файлы нужно переименовать, потом можно и терминалы стартануть.

Comment: @KoVadim, *это лечится просто* — ну, я обычно из двух путей «вообще не болеть» и «лечиться просто» предпочту всё-таки первый.

Comment: @KoVadim: есть [`tmux-continuum` плагин](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum), который позволяет не прерываясь с tmux работать после перезагрузок системы. tmux позволяет одновременно работать с несколькими терминальными сессиями в одном окне.

Answer (score 0):

При выходе (при выполнении встроенной команды `exit` в login shell или завершении интерактивной login shell), bash читает  `~/.bash_logout` (если доступен).

Чтобы запомнить последнюю открытую директорию в баше перед выходом, можно добавить в `~/.bash_logout` файл:

```
pwd > ~/.last-dir
```

При входе пользователя ([по имени/паролю, используя `su - <username>`или `sudo -u me -i` или через ssh, или `bash -l`](https://askubuntu.com/q/155865/3712)), bash читает *первый доступный* файл из [`~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile` в приведённом порядке](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html).

Чтобы автоматически перейти в последнюю сохранённую директорию, можно добавить в использующийся startup-файл:

```
cd $(< ~/.last-dir)
```

Указанные файлы НЕ читаются, если вы просто Gnome Terminal откроете (non-login shell будет запущен).

Если вы хотите, чтобы использовалась последняя рабочая директория из любого экземпляра bash, не ожидая входа/выхода из системы, то воспользуйтесь [@alexander barakin ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/605279/23044), манипулирующим prompt.